# IEnumerable or List Property in a C# interface

Tags: c#, c++-cli, ogre

I'm trying to design an interface in C# that's being used in C++ CLI afterwards.

The C++ CLI class that implements the C# interface needs to have a list like property that can be iterated through. This class is actually a wrapper for a native (if you want the full details, it contains a pointer to an Ogre RenderWindow object that has a list of Viewports, each Viewport item is easily accessible through a RenderWindow property called getViewport(int index) ).

The goal is to have a property in the interface AND in the C++ CLI implementation of this interface, such that it can be used with the `for each` construct. What would be the cleanest way to do this?

Some snippets of the discussed items:

*The C# interface*:

```
public interface IRenderWindow
    {
         bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

*And the C++ CLI implementer*

```
public ref class CLIOgreRenderWindow : public IRenderWindow
        {
        private:
            Ogre::RenderWindow * mRenderWindow;
        public:
            CLIOgreRenderWindow();

            virtual property bool IsActive 
            {
                bool get() sealed {return mRenderWindow->isActive();}
                void set(bool value) sealed { mRenderWindow->setActive(value); }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to expose the list of Viewports.  If that is the case, then you can:

1. Create a wrapper ref class for your native Viewport objects (just like you did for CLIOgreRenderWindow.
2. Have the IRenderWindow expose a IEnumerable with a getter.
3. In your C++/CLI implementation you could create a managed Array/List of the wrapper objects (based on the native objects), and return that.

Item #3 above is where you can do something different depending on your requirements (i.e. you could implement IEnumerable to yield one result at a time--though that's a bit more work).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the simpler approach first and see if it's missing any versatility.

Comment: This approach will do, I'd further recommend it.. thanks for the answer.